# Is Webmedcentral a reputable scientific publisher?

Tags: literature

I am a student, and I have written a paper (in drug discovery) which I want to publish. While searching for possible journals I came across [Webmedcentral](http://www.webmedcentral.com).

Is Webmedcentral a reputable scientific publisher?
What is the impact factor for this journal?

Answer (score 2):

I checked this site and its journals in Scopus.com based on its "ISSN 2046-1690" but nothing was there. they are fast in submitting and publishing but it is not some thing great by it self. I think maybe its better to find some where better to publish your article(s).